# Why reference to constant before declaration does not throw?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Why the following code does not throw at line `(*)`?

```js
{
  function update() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  const THROTTLE_TIMEOUT = 1000;
  let throttled = false;

  function stopThrottling() {
    throttled = false;
  }

  function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
    if (throttled) return; throttled = true;
    setTimeout(stopThrottling, THROTTLE_TIMEOUT);

    update.call(Tracker); // (*)
  }

  //console.log(Tracker); // Throws

  const Tracker = {
    attached() {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
    }
  }

  Tracker.attached();
}
```

Comment: The function is called after the variable is set. Start the code in your debugger and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

The function is called after the variable is set.

The variable `Tracker` is set between

```
//console.log(Tracker); // Throws
```

and

```
Tracker.attached();
```

The line

```
update.call(Tracker);
```

isn't called before

```
Tracker.attached();
```

Follow the program flow in your debugger or add some `console.log` debugging to see it.